# Reading text file truncates line output in PHP

Tags: php, file

Reading text file truncates line output in PHP:

## Text-file:

```
NEXT_GEN_TO="Project Bribara<project-automation@bribara.com>"
```

## Code:

```
$lines = file('Text-file');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   echo "$line</br>";
}
```

## Expected:

```
NEXT_GEN_TO="Project Bribara<project-automation@bribara.com>"
```

## Actual:

```
NEXT_GEN_TO="Project Bribara"
```

How can I print expected result after reading the lines from file?

Comment: If you inspect the output document, can you see the full text there? If so, using `htmlspecialchars()` on the output might be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give output like this...

```
echo htmlentities($line) . "</br>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<project-automation@bribara.com>` is treated as an html tag by your browser. If you check out the outputted html source code for the page using "View Source" in your browser, it's all going to be there.

Use one of the php functions to turn html into non-html text such as htmlentities() on the text before output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php